# How to finish activity when tapping outside an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to finish or dismiss activity when tapping outside a certain component like an ImageView or TextView ? And if it is ... how to do that ?

code of my layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
tools:ignore="PxUsage,UselessParent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contents"
    android:layout_width="720px"
    android:layout_height="1280px"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shortcutImageView"
        android:layout_width="533px"
        android:layout_height="727px"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15px"
        android:layout_marginTop="165px"
        android:background="@drawable/shortcut_bg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageDesc" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I want to finish activity whenever tapped outside of this ImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First code your xml like that:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in your activity:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev)
        {
            finish();
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Hope this work for you...

Answer (score 2):

Simply attach `onClickListener` to root of your layout (most likely you got there `LinearLayout` or so) and then do regular `finish()` when that element gets tapped.

Comment: I want the action to be when tapped outside of that element not inside it

Comment: the root of your layout is the outside of your imageview / textview

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `RelativeLayout` attribute `android:clickable="true"` in the xml layout file OR `setClickable(true)` in the java activity code. Simply call `finish();` to finish the current activity in onClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using a `FragmentActivity` or another subclass of the `Activity` class you can set it to finish itself when touched outside the window's bounds by calling [`setFinishOnTouchOutside`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setFinishOnTouchOutside(boolean)) when creating the activity

```
setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Comment: @IbrahimMAATKI how am I supposed to know? Neither `ImageView`, nor `RelativeLayout`, nor `FragmentLayout` are subclasses of `Activity`...I clearly mentioned that on my answer. However, now that you posted your layout I have to say that it is NOT going to work in your case scenario. Nevertheless, I'll leave the answer as it is since your question has already been answered by "Marcin Orlowski". Leaving the answer here just as a reference for anyone else coming from Google since this might work for other scenarios with minimal coding efforts

Answer (score 0):

```
   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.contents);
               layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   finish();    
                }
            });

            this.initContent();
```